# Donde hacer una pagina de inicio en Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Que me recomiendan para una pagina de inicio en Wordpress:
 - Hacer una pagina y usarla como portada?
 - Usar el home.php o front-page.php?
 - Hacerlo directamente en index.php?

Cual seria la opcion mas conveniente???

gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress no funciona de esa manera, debes hacer una página dentro del CMS,  luego en *Ajustes* -> *Lectura* puedes seleccionar como inicio una página estática la página que hiciste.

En caso de querer modificar la apariencia, entonces debes editar el **page.php** o **front-page.php**

Para mas información, puedes consultar la documentación oficial en: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

Comment: El archivo home.php tambien me puede servir como la pagina de inicio... lo que pasa es que no quiero que modifiquen la pagina de inicio, si hago una pagina y la nombro como portada tendria que restringir con los niveles de usuario, cosa que si hago el home.php no tendrian manera de modificar atraves de WP sino directamente, estoy en lo correcto???

Comment: Si, estas en lo correcto.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress funciona por plantillas o temas (Themes), estos están ubicados en la carpeta /wp-content/themes/ para agregar una nueva plantilla solo hay que subirla por FTP o a traves de un panel como Cpanel a dicho directorio (Descomprimido, no funciona si subes un archivo en formato .zip o .rar).
Si lo que deseas es crear tu propia plantilla solo tienes que crear una carpeta en dicho directorio con el nombre que quieras y agregar lo siguiente:

```
styles.css <-- Aparte de ser la hoja de estilos de tu sitio da de alta tu tema en el sistema de wordpress (Pero no activa tu plantilla) -->
<-- 
Tu archivo styles.css deberá contener:
/*
Theme Name: Este es el nombre de tu plantilla
Theme URI: http://example.com
Description: Diseñoo #1 de mi propiedad
Author: Jorhel Reyes
Author URI: http://facebook.com/king.jorhel
Version: 1
*/
-->
index.php <-- Será la portada de tu página -->
header.php <-- La parte de arriba de todas tus páginas, si no se espefica, todas tus secciones deberán tener un diseño distinto, para agregar el contenido de este archivo debes agregar en el codigo de tu página (ej: index.php) wp_header(); -->
footer.php <-- la parte de abajo de tu página, las mismas condiciones que header, para incluir el contenido de este deberás agregar wp_footer(); -->
single.php <-- en donde se mostrarán tus entradas o posts, se manejan por bucles, investiga "the_post()" -->
category.php <-- Lista las entradas de una categoria en concreto (tambien maneja bucles) -->
page.php <-- las secciones de tu página, estas no se pueden anidar en categorías por eso tienen un archivo diferente, aunque su estructura es casi la misma que en single.php -->
```

Estas son las más usadas, de aqui tenemos, comments, author, 404, etc, etc.
Si no especificas alguno de estos archivos (excepto header y footer) el sistema mostrará index.php

Acá un ejemplo mejor explicado: http://www.esandra.com/crear-plantilla-wordpress-desde-cero/?ref=https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56193/donde-hacer-una-pagina-de-inicio-en-wordpress

Comment: Gracias amigo!! si entendi lo de la jerarquia de archivos de WP, solo que no sabia en que plantilla va... investigando un poco mas, puedes crear templates para tener diferentes diseños de paginas!! espero estar en lo correcto!!

Answer (score 0):

Recomiendo que hagas una pagina (puede estar vacía) y en Ajustes->Lectura la selecciones como estatica.

Ademas de lo anterior si queres que sea un diseño completamente diferente, crea una pagina por ejemplo "**portada**" y tu diseño de php/html guardalo en el directorio de la plantilla con el nombre "**page-portada.php**" (page-{slug}.php), aun con esta opcion debes seleccionarla en Ajustes->Lectura como estática.